# ValueError: index must be monotonic when applying rolling("2H").mean()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
                   TIME     DELAY
0   2016-01-01 06:30:00     0
1   2016-01-01 14:10:00     2
2   2016-01-01 07:05:00     2
3   2016-01-01 11:00:00     1
4   2016-01-01 10:40:00     0
5   2016-01-01 08:10:00     7
6   2016-01-01 11:35:00     2
7   2016-01-02 13:50:00     2
8   2016-01-02 14:50:00     4
9   2016-01-02 14:05:00     1
```

Please notice that row are not sorted by a datetime object.

For each row I want to know the average delay for the last 2 hours. To do this task, I executed the following code:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["TIME"])
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()
```

However I got this error:

```
ValueError: index must be monotonic
```

How can I properly solve my task?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Problem is `DatetimeIndex` is not sorted, so need [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["TIME"])
df = df.sort_index()
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()
print (df)
                                    TIME  DELAY  DELAY_LAST2HOURS
TIME                                                             
2016-01-01 06:30:00  2016-01-01 06:30:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 07:05:00  2016-01-01 07:05:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 08:10:00  2016-01-01 08:10:00      7          3.000000
2016-01-01 10:40:00  2016-01-01 10:40:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 11:00:00  2016-01-01 11:00:00      1          0.500000
2016-01-01 11:35:00  2016-01-01 11:35:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 14:10:00  2016-01-01 14:10:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 13:50:00  2016-01-02 13:50:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 14:05:00  2016-01-02 14:05:00      1          1.500000
2016-01-02 14:50:00  2016-01-02 14:50:00      4          2.333333
```

All together should be if not necessary original `TIME` column:

```
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"])

df = df.set_index('TIME').sort_index()
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()
print (df)
                     DELAY  DELAY_LAST2HOURS
TIME                                        
2016-01-01 06:30:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 07:05:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 08:10:00      7          3.000000
2016-01-01 10:40:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 11:00:00      1          0.500000
2016-01-01 11:35:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 14:10:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 13:50:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 14:05:00      1          1.500000
2016-01-02 14:50:00      4          2.333333
```

EDIT:

```
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"])
df = df.sort_values('TIME').set_index('TIME')

df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()
```

Comment: How can I get TIME among column names? When should I do reset_index()?

Comment: @ScalaBoy - Not sure if understand, but try edited answer with all code.

Comment: The problem is that I get the error `KeyError: "['TIME'] not in index"` when I do `df[["TIME","DELAY","DELAY_LAST2HOURS"]].head()`. I tried an edit, but still have the same issue. Is it possible to maintain `TIME` in the columns list of `df`?

Comment: @ScalaBoy - hmmm, maybe `TIME` is already datetimeIndex, what return `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: It returns `Int64Index([     0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,
                 8,      9,
            ...
            125137, 125138, 125139, 125140, 125141, 125142, 125143, 125144,
            125145, 125146],
           dtype='int64', length=125147)`

Comment: @ScalaBoy - OK, sa what are real columns names? `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Sorry, I posted a wrong output. This is what I get with `print(df.index)` after running your code: `DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 06:30:00', '2016-01-01 07:05:00',
               '2016-01-01 07:45:00', '2016-01-01 07:45:00',
               '2016-01-01 08:00:00', '2016-01-01 08:00:00',
               '2016-01-01 08:10:00', '2016-01-01 08:10:00',
               ...
               '2016-12-31 08:00:00', '2016-12-31 08:05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TIME', length=125147, freq=None)`

Comment: @ScalaBoy - Yes, there is DatetimeIndex, so need only `df = df.sort_index()
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()`

Comment: I did `df = df.reset_index()` after running your code in order to bring `TIME` back to the list of columns. Now I can run `df[["TIME","DELAY","DELAY_LAST2HOURS"]].head()`.