# How to shift moving average when using "rolling" function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame df:

```
                   TIME     DELAY
0   2016-01-01 06:30:00     0
1   2016-01-01 14:10:00     2
2   2016-01-01 07:05:00     2
3   2016-01-01 11:00:00     1
4   2016-01-01 10:40:00     0
5   2016-01-01 08:10:00     7
6   2016-01-01 11:35:00     2
7   2016-01-02 13:50:00     2
8   2016-01-02 14:50:00     4
9   2016-01-02 14:05:00     1
```

As suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421871/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-when-applying-rolling2h-mean/54421898?noredirect=1#comment95654121_54421898) by @jezrael, I used the following code to calculate a rolling average for the last 2 hours.

```
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIME"])

df = df.sort_values('TIME').set_index('TIME')
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean()
print (df)
```

This is what I get:

```
                     DELAY  DELAY_LAST2HOURS
TIME                                        
2016-01-01 06:30:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 07:05:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 08:10:00      7          3.000000
2016-01-01 10:40:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 11:00:00      1          0.500000
2016-01-01 11:35:00      2          1.000000
2016-01-01 14:10:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 13:50:00      2          2.000000
2016-01-02 14:05:00      1          1.500000
2016-01-02 14:50:00      4          2.333333
```

However, is it possible to shift a rolling average in order to not account for a current row. This is an example of expected output for the first four rows:

```
2016-01-01 06:30:00      0          0.000000
2016-01-01 07:05:00      2          0.000000
2016-01-01 08:10:00      7          1.000000
2016-01-01 10:40:00      0          3.000000
```

Comment: Do you need `df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean().shift().fillna(0)` ?

Comment: @jezrael: Probably:) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want shift by 1 row use:

```
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean().shift().fillna(0)
print (df)
                     DELAY  DELAY_LAST2HOURS
TIME                                        
2016-01-01 06:30:00      0               0.0
2016-01-01 07:05:00      2               0.0
2016-01-01 08:10:00      7               1.0
2016-01-01 10:40:00      0               3.0
2016-01-01 11:00:00      1               0.0
2016-01-01 11:35:00      2               0.5
2016-01-01 14:10:00      2               1.0
2016-01-02 13:50:00      2               2.0
2016-01-02 14:05:00      1               2.0
2016-01-02 14:50:00      4               1.5
```

EDIT: pandas 0.24.0 solution - parameter `fill_value` in [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df["DELAY_LAST2HOURS"] = df["DELAY"].rolling("2H").mean().shift(fill_value=0)
print (df)
                     DELAY  DELAY_LAST2HOURS
TIME                                        
2016-01-01 06:30:00      0               0.0
2016-01-01 07:05:00      2               0.0
2016-01-01 08:10:00      7               1.0
2016-01-01 10:40:00      0               3.0
2016-01-01 11:00:00      1               0.0
2016-01-01 11:35:00      2               0.5
2016-01-01 14:10:00      2               1.0
2016-01-02 13:50:00      2               2.0
2016-01-02 14:05:00      1               2.0
2016-01-02 14:50:00      4               1.5
```